# Bresenham's line algorithm. Does exist ncurses output for file?

Tags: c++, algorithm, bresenham

I have homework, ASCII line plot drawer. I must print graph into to file. All algoritms of Bresenham's line algoritm have function SetPixel ( x, y ); in loops. This function must print pixel by x and y. NCurses library is idealy solution for print on windows console, but I must print into file.txt. I think that Ncurses only print on window console. My question: How to implement SetPixel function for print into file in this code? :

```
void Line( const float x1, const float y1, const float x2, const float y2, const Color& color )
{
        // Bresenham's line algorithm
    const bool steep = (fabs(y2 - y1) > fabs(x2 - x1));
    if(steep)
    {
        std::swap(x1, y1);
        std::swap(x2, y2);
    }

    if(x1 > x2)
    {
        std::swap(x1, x2);
        std::swap(y1, y2);
    }

    const float dx = x2 - x1;
    const float dy = fabs(y2 - y1);

    float error = dx / 2.0f;
    const int ystep = (y1 < y2) ? 1 : -1;
    int y = (int)y1;

    const int maxX = (int)x2;

    for(int x=(int)x1; x<maxX; x++)
    {
        if(steep)
                {
                        SetPixel(y,x, color);
                }
        else
                {
                        SetPixel(x,y, color);
                }

                error -= dy;
            if(error < 0)
            {
                y += ystep;
                error += dx;
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To save this to a file, you will need to do some initial calculations before writing data to a file. I suggest that you create a data structure (perhaps an array) to keep track of each "pixel". For example, you can declare

```
char graph[100][100];
```

Each element of `graph` is either a space or a `'X'`. Use Bresenham's line algoritm to calculate the elements in `graph` which should be set to `'X'` and then write the array to a file.

Answer (score 1):

First make an instance of a dynamic structure, preferably `std::vector`. I suggest to separate x and y for ease, e.g `std::vector<int> x_points, y_points`. Then, from your `for loop` body, record all coordinates i.e that (x,y). Then create a function that [writes all the data from your vector into a file](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need NCurses to save ASCII, just create a plain text file and save the output of the Bresenham's algorithm in there. I suggest you use a [different implementation of the algorithm](http://roguebasin.roguelikedevelopment.org/index.php?title=Bresenham%27s_Line_Algorithm) aswell.